# Custom CSS in the admin panel

Tags: css, admin-panel

We have installed Venus theme `Megamenu PRO` plugin into Magento 2 site. After installing it, we can see that they are providing an option **Custom CSS** to write CSS into the admin panel. Please see the screenshot:

[image]

Here's my query, what will happen if I write the CSS on there and update the Magento version. Do the CSS will be removed from the admin panel?.

Could anyone please guide me?

Comment: no it will not be removed since their custom css is saved to the database.

Comment: @magefms Thanks for your information.